# Не открывается бэк по адресу 0.0.0.0

Tags: django, docker, localhost, hosts

Проблема в следующем, есть сервер написанный на Django, через docker-compose проходит запуск сервера вместе с PosgreSQl. Итоговый адрес такой http://0.0.0.0:8000/. Но по этому адресу он не открывается, только если поменять на 127.0.0.1:8000. Никаких ошибок в самом коде нет. Я подозреваю, что у меня этот хост заблочен, но как это проверить я хз, в гугле нашел только как открыть порт, что я и пытался но результата никакого.
[image: Результат открытия через 0.0.0.0]
[image: Через 127.0.0.0]

Comment: И не должен открываться, 0.0.0.0 просто означает прослушивание всех доступных сетевых интерфейсов

Comment: Но до этого ведь открывался, и повторюсь, что у человека который разрабатывал открывается.